# How to limit import that may throw

Tags: python

I have a class that will normally run under Windows and uses the win32com module.  I also have a mock version of this class, both for testing and for demo purposes, which imports from the original, and should be able to run anywhere.  So, it's like this, in two files:

```
import win32com.client
class basic():
    def local_instance(self):
        # called once during setup of execution
        res = win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar')
    def res_attrib(self):
        # called repeatedly by threads; must re-instantiate COM obj
        return win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar').Attribute
    def otherstuf(self):
        ...

=======================
from basic import basic

class mock(basic):
    def local_instance(self):
        res = mock_foobar()    # mock implementation with .Attribute
    def res_attrib(self):
        return res.Attribute   # mock implementation, this is OK
    # otherwise uses otherstuf() unchanged
```

The problem with this is when the mock version is loaded in an environment without win32com, the `import win32com.client` statement throws.

My question is, what's the correct approach to limiting the application of that import?

- embed the import inside each of the methods, where it will be executed repeatedly:

  ```
  def local_instance(self):
      import win32com.client
      res = win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar')
  def res_attrib(self):
      import win32com.client
      return win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar').Attribute
  ```
- nest the import and the def's inside a try block, where it will fail strangely if user tries to run basic in a Windows environment but doesn't happen to have win32com installed:

  ```
  try:
      import win32com.client
      def local_instance(self):
          res = win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar')
      def res_attrib(self):
          return win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar').Attribute
  except:
      # alternate or no defs
  ```
- or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> nest the import and the def's inside a try block,

This is the standard approach that most people use.

Do this **outside** any class definitions.  At the very top level with your ordinary imports.  Once only.

Use the two functions within any class definition which occurs *after* this in the module.

```
try:
    import win32com.client
    def local_instance():
        res = win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar')
    def res_attrib():
        return win32com.client.Dispatch('Foo.Bar').Attribute
except ImportError, why:
    # alternate or no defs
```

> where it will fail strangely if user tries to run basic in a Windows environment but doesn't happen to have win32com installed:

This is not true at all.

First, you can examine the `why` variable.

Second, you can examine `os.name` or `platform.uname()` to see if this is Win32 and alter the `except` block based on operating system.

Comment: OK, this is helpful.  I refined your approach to define the methods within the except clause to re-raise the ImportError; that way, if they're called in a non-mock situation, the correct exception is thrown (yay closure) but in a mock situation, there is no problem.

Comment: Well, that didn't quite work.  Putting the import within class scope and then using it in the methods yields undefined symbol on normal execution.  So I put the import at global scope and carried the error down to an `if` in the class definition; that seems to do the trick.

Comment: As a side note, you'd use `except ImportError as why:` in Python 3. Personally I like using `e` or `err` as the variable instead of your usage of `why`, but that's just me.

Comment: @Mike C: "Putting the import within class scope?"  Don't.  Those are global functions that the class will use.

Comment: @S.Lott: I thought my question made it clear that that's what I was considering, as the def's originally appeared in a class context.  I see I forgot to include the `self` in the method definitions, tho, which may have led to confusion.  Will edit.

Comment: @Mike C: Why waste time trying to get this to work inside a class scope?  It's much simpler to do this at a global scope.

Comment: @S.Lott: maybe you missed the part of my earlier comment where I said I'd already backed away from that approach.

Comment: @Mike C: Maybe you missed the part of my earlier comment where I said it's simpler to do this globally, not within a class.

Answer (score 1):

S.Lott has the real answer, but let me adress a possible miconception: "embed the import inside each of the methods, where it will be executed repeatedly:"

While technically the import statement itself would indeed execute multiple times if imbedded in each method, the interpreter will only actually process the module the first time.  Subsequent calls to import an already imported module won't actually do anything or take any measurable time.  This was designed for effeciency reasons.  There is some discussion of this at: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.htm under section 6.1.